# Problem with the network interface in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm trying connect a GoPro to an Android device with the USB port.

In theory, the GoPro creates a local network and I can send commands to send it orders. The problems seem like in Android 13 always send the commands by the Wifi network interface and I always get an error saying that do not exists that URL. I guess it is because the device is trying to send the command by the Wifi interface. When I disable the wifi, in some devices with Android 13 works and I can send commands to the GoPro

In Android <13 I can't send commands, even with the Wifi disabled.

For example, in iOS automatically create the network and I can access to the network and send commands.

Any idea about this?

I've tried to connect the GoPro by wire to an Android device and with an app like Postman send commands to control the GoPro, the commands are correct, tested in iOS.

Comment: So unclear. `In theory, the GoPro creates a local network and I can send commands to send it orders` Well how are you sending commands then? But worse: if there is a network then why do you try to connect with a usb cable?

Comment: When a GoPro is connected, create a network and I in theory, I can send http commands to the url created by the GoPro, the url is like: http://172.27.189.51.
I would like connect with a usb cable because I want continue with internet via Wifi and if I connect by Wifi the GoPro I don't have internet

Comment: For example, I use the app REST Api Client in the device. With the GoPro plugged I try to send commands and I get a timeout. If I disconnect the Wifi and the mobile data, the commands are sended correctly.